# DOM doesn't get refreshed using CEFSharp native functions

Tags: javascript, c++-cli, cefsharp

I am using CEFSharp, and register some C++/CLI native functions, one of the functions is time consuming so there is a busy icon in the html page. I expect that this busy icon is shown when this time-consuming native function is called, however, the icon got stuck since the DOM doesn't get refreshed when the native function is called:

Native function:

```
public ref class ActivationForm : Form
    {
    public:
        ActivationForm(void)
        {
        }

        ActivationForm(MainAppForm^ iHost, String^ iTitle)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this->webBrowser->RegisterJsObject("FormWrapper", gcnew ActivationForm::FormWrapper(this->webBrowser, this));
        }

    private:

        CefSharp::WinForms::WebView^ webBrowser;
        ref class FormWrapper
        {
            CefSharp::WinForms::WebView^  webBrowser;
            ActivationForm^ mActivationForm;

        public:
            FormWrapper(CefSharp::WinForms::WebView^ iWebBrowser, ActivationForm^ iActivationForm)
            {
                webBrowser = iWebBrowser;
                mActivationForm = iActivationForm;
            }


            int activateMail(String^ iMail, String^ callback);
        };

int ActivationForm::FormWrapper::activateMail(String^ iMail, String^ callback)
    {
        //connect to activation server
    }
```

js code:

```
function activateExistingUser() {
    ...

        if (!window.FormWrapper.activateMail(emailAddress)) {
            isWaitingForTask = false;
            me.displayFullInfoWindow();
        }

    }
```

Is there any solution to make the DOM get refreshed and show the busy icon? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you've found out bound methods are executed in a sync fashion. The approach I'd recommend is spawn a 'Task', return immediate and call `ExecuteScriptAsync` to effectively `Callback` into your web page.

There is work in progress to add async callbacks, which should be included in version `39`, https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/868 has information if your interested.

Comment: CefSharp `39.0.0` has been released including the ability to provide a function callback. The Example project provides a complete demo

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/BoundObject.cs#L23
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/Resources/BindingTest.html#L19